# SetPos() doesn't display properly outside of MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

While I'm trying to move objects inside a scene made in constructor, when I call move() in some other place than constructor, it does change items x and y coordinates but doesn't move the object in the scene. However when I use move() method inside MainWindow constructor it does work. I have my objects stored in a vector.
What difference does it make if I call the method function from constructor versus some other method inside the MainWindow?

Comment: How about a [mcve]?

Comment: MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui_(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
myscene.addrect(object)
myvector.back().setpos(0,0)} #works here
move()
}
move(){
myvector.back().setpos(10,10) #doesn't do anything
}

Comment: Please, read again [mcve]. Then, please, [edit] your question to add a [mcve]. This code fragment in comment is definitely not a [mcve], or do you think if I copy/paste and compile it it will me reproduce your issue?

Comment: Problem occurs when I'm trying to call the function by using a button.

Comment: I need to update the scene inside the method, however it updates itself in the constructor it seems like.